# ggplot and gather with different value levels and group_by

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a bar plot using the frequencies of different character values of a dataset. I have 4 questions with different levels that need to be plot using facet_wrap

Behaviour: even using group_by ggplot uses all the character value to plot the frequencies resulting in a nonsense plot.

[image]
Expected Behaviour: 4 different facets with their relative levels.

```
  `difficulty_pre_How was the pace of the class?` `difficulty_pre_How muc… `difficulty_pre_How m… `difficulty_pre_Conside…
  <chr>                                           <chr>                    <chr>                  <chr>                   
1 About right                                     51-75%                   1-25%                  About right             
2 Too slow                                        51-75%                   91-100%                Very easy               
3 Too fast                                        51-75%                   76-90%                 About right             
4 About right                                     1-25%                    91-100%                About right             
5 Fast                                            51-75%                   26-50%                 About right
```

My code:

```
data %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
  gather() %>%
  mutate(key = str_sub(key, start = 16)) %>% #need to cut unecessary letter from key 
  group_by(key,value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_wrap(~ key) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.9))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=6))
```

Comment: adding `scale='free_x'` inside `facet_wrap()` should do the work

Comment: ggplot pays no attention to `group_by`

Comment: @RichardTelford did not know, thanks !

Comment: @GGamba Amazing, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: As suggested by GGamba adding `scale='free_x'` inside `facet_wrap()`

```
data 
%>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
  gather() %>%
  mutate(key = str_sub(key, start = 16)) %>% #need to cut unecessary letter from key 
  group_by(key,value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_wrap(~ key,scale='free_x') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.9))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=6))
```